# Uncaught TypeError: $.getscript is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the `$.getscript` to execute a function in another .js file, but I'm getting an error which I'm not sure what means.

My code:

```
$.getscript("Tool_Functions.js",function(){
     getGraphData(id)
         .done(function (graphResponse) {
             Drawgraph(graphResponse);                 
         })
         .fail(function (x) {
             // Fail code
         });
});
```

Is it because of the function being asynchronous?

Comment: It's `getScript()` not `getscript()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. You just have to use `getScript()` instead of `getscript()`.

Comment: Yes, I already noted that in my comment.

Comment: Questions which indicate a typo are unlikely to help others. Please do not answer them. You should be able to flag them for closure.